# Javascript - Double callbacks from chrome extension not working with "this"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, object, callback, this

I've builded a Chrome extension to do cross-domain ajax requests...
Now I'm trying to wrap it into a javascript object oriented framework. Here is the code:

```
function webpage(url)
{
    this.url = url;
    this.html = "";
}

webpage.prototype.set_html = function(html)
{
    console.log(html); // working
    this.html = html; // not working
}

webpage.prototype.get_html = function()
{
    request_url(this.url, this.set_html); // call to a working chrome extension
}

var mypage = new webpage("http://www.google.it");
mypage.get_html();
```

The problem is that the prototype function "set_html" is working great if I call it "the normal way"

```
mypage.set_html("hello world")
```

The function "request_url" is working great too

```
request_url("http://www.google.it",function(data){console.log(data)})
```

However when I call it like this

```
mypage.get_html();
```

The first "console.log" works great and it shows the page_source but the value of this.html won't change... Where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a duplicate as similar questions about this have been asked many times. For completeness I'll answer it with a reference to what `this` is in JavaScript. One solution to your problem could be to pass a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) to request_url instead of the function:

```
webpage.prototype.get_html = function()
{
  var me = this;
  request_url(this.url, function(){me.set_html(arguments);});
}
```

Or you can use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind): (may need a polyfil for older browsers like IE 8)

```
webpage.prototype.get_html = function()
{
  request_url(this.url, this.set_html.bind(this));
}
```

More on constructor functions and the value of `this` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941) (under The this variable)

Comment: Thank you! This made the trick!